# ActiveAdmin: routes for overridden controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I want to override login for activeadmin. I created `SessionsController` and override `create` action like

```
class Admin::SessionsController < ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    session[:zzz] = 1
    logger.debug("@@@ #{session[:zzz]}")
    super
  end

end
```

How should I apply the changes for activeadmin devise controller?

for devise I would make it like

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'users/sessions'}
```

in routes.rb

my routes.rb for ActiveAdmin

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

Comment: How can we make two-page for each kind of user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to add overrided controller's code to the bottom of `config/active_admin.rb`

```
class Admin::SessionsController < ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    session[:zzz] = 1
    logger.debug("@@@ #{session[:zzz]}")
    super
  end

end
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to create few more methods so can i do a two factor authentication. I tried your answer but it didnt worked but i found one more solution by which i am able to over ride create but not able to add new methods so i can redirect to a two step form.